# I continue to receive MPI errors whether I set MPI Parallel to false or true

Tags: python, makefile, compiler-errors, mpi

I am trying to run the permeability tutorial within the Palabos Software, however, I continue to receive the following error:

I tried turning Parallel MPI from true to false within the make file but still the same error.

```
~(0.0)~ /scratch/06535/sammyjo/palabos-v2.0r0/examples/tutorial/permeability
[182] 01:33 PM sammyjo permeability $ ./permeability twoSpheres.dat tmp/ 48 64 64 0.00005
[Tue Jul  9 13:33:37 2019] [unknown] Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(537):
MPID_Init(246).......: channel initialization failed
MPID_Init(638).......:  PMI2 init failed: 1
aborting job:
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(537):
MPID_Init(246).......: channel initialization failed
MPID_Init(638).......:  PMI2 init failed: 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to figure out what the problem is. You can try to run an MPI hello-world program (https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/) and see whether MPI is working.
Thank you